# AppStore submission: ERROR ITMS-9000: "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'MyApp.app/BuildAgent' is not permitted

Tags: ios, app-store, xcode6, ipa, submission

I'm stuck with the following error which I simply don't even understand.

ERROR ITMS-9000: "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'MyApp.app/BuildAgent' is not permitted. Your app may contain only one executable file.

When I export from the Archive with Xcode to IPA, I see that BuildAgent as 0 entitlement. Is that related to my error? What's a BuildAgent? How should I fix this?

[image]

Comment: by any chance, have you used `HockeySDK`?

Comment: Yes I have. @AsifAsif

Comment: You may want to remove 'BuildAgent' from `Build Phases` -> `Copy Bundle Resources` or remove any existing reference to it.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much @AsifAsif you made my day. Please write it as the answer so that I can check it. Btw, what should I do with the call to HockeyApp for the AppStore Version? Should I remove it from the app?

Comment: Is that call concerned with `BuildAgent`?

Comment: Nope. Just wondering what to do with the following code when publishing to App Store?     
    [[BITHockeyManager sharedHockeyManager] configureWithIdentifier:[UIApplication distributionKey]];
    [[BITHockeyManager sharedHockeyManager] startManager];
    [[BITHockeyManager sharedHockeyManager].authenticator authenticateInstallation];

Comment: I am sure it won't be a problem with app store review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove any reference to `BuildAgent` executable file that was accompanied with the `HockeySDK-iOS`