# Extra binary shows up in Xcode archive

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, sandbox, code-signing

I have a small app that consists of 2 targets, an app and a framework thats included as an embedded binary in the first app:

[image]

These are the only two products in my project:

[image]

Yet whenever I code sign and archive the app, an extra called 'A' shows up:
[image]

I have checked the project folder and there is no directory or file called A. Has anyone else ever experienced this? And is there a way to remove it? The app is sandboxed if this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the 'A' seems to come from the the framework which by deafault is stored under /Versions/A, and this only seems to happen when its code signed

Answer (score 0):

I'm also experiencing this issue.. going CRAZY here... have no idea what to do with this error.

Finally I've managed to fix this! (ref for same issue [AppStore submission: ERROR ITMS-9000: "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'MyApp.app/BuildAgent' is not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26443429/appstore-submission-error-itms-9000-invalid-bundle-structure-the-binary-fil))

Here's how i did it:

1. Remove all the stuff related to whatever SDK/Framework you've added and cause the issue
2. Choose your target -> Build Phases -> press + on Link Binary With Libraries (choose add other... and add only the .a file)
3. Drag all the rest of the files for the SDK/Framework (do NOT drag the .a file also)

Clean + Archive and you're good to go!

Answer (score 0):

Faced same problem today!

Select your main App target, and go to Build Phases. Under "Copy Bundle Resources",I had to remove the "APPNAME EXTENSION App.app".

After that, I was able to submit my App to the App Store.